# How to create dynamic vectors in jsp?

Tags: jsp

Is there any way to create dynamic vectors using jsp. Advance thanks to you all.

Comment: could you provide a real use case or is this for learning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Vector" language="java" %>
<%
Vector vc=new Vector();
%>

<html>
<body>
    <%
     int i=0;
     for(i=0;i<vc.size();i++)
     {
      vc.add("vector" + i);
     }
    %>
</body>
</html>
```